# Why are my raspberry floricanes dying?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases

I have a good size raspberry patch in my yard that was there when I bought my house, and for the first 2 years I lived here I got a ton of raspberries.  Starting last year, early in the summer, the leaves on the floricanes started turning yellow, and eventually the cane would die back from the tip down. Primocanes seemed to be less affected, but I did lose some later in the season.  This year I watched for it and it is bad.  All the floricanes have yellow leaves and are dying with fruit on them.  I have gone to the Connecticut Agricultural center twice with cuttings and they found no evidence of fungus or other diseases.  Nice green primocanes are growing up between the dying floricanes.  Would a lack of water kill the old growth but not affect the new growth?  I didn't realize how much water then needed so they probably got too dry, but the leaves were showing some signs of yellowing in the spring when it was still rainy and they were starting to flower.  I did a soil test last year and everything was good except Nitrogen, which was severely lacking.  I fertilized with blood meal at that point.  Where it got the worst last year, the plants are only about 18" tall and don't look good. The whole patch is being destroyed!   [image][image]

Comment: Did you test your soil again after amending it?

Comment: Not after I added the blood meal.  The new growth greened up more (already looked pretty good at first), but no change to the floricanes. 
Can cane borers do this kind of damage?  I went out yesterday and cut every floricane to the ground since hey were dying anyway, and saw most of the primocanes had the telltale rings from cane borers at the tips.  (I just learned about these little #$#% a couple days ago...)